# Variable ratio matching

Tags: matching, case-control-study

I am working on a simulated study where I have variable number of control matches for my treatment subjects. I am new to this type of analysis. I realize after matching I can utilize logistic regression and use dummy variable for match pair as one way to analyze 1:n (n - variable) matched data, another way is Mantel–Haenszel chisquare. However, what's the correct way to evaluate difference in outcomes when outcome is not binary?